# Separate the files in one directory to different files by .sh and .txt .gz

Tags: shell, unix

I want to copy the present working directory files to respective files like below.
.sh file--->sh_files
.txt file--->txt_files

I did try with below script but getting some errors 
"cut: txt.1a: No such file or directory"
can any have alternate script for this scenario.suggest on this....

```
ls -f >list_files.txt
for i in `cat list_files.txt`
do
rev1=`echo $i | rev` 
k=`cut -c 1-3 $rev1`
if[ "$k"= ".sh"]
then
echo $i >file_sh.txt
else 
echo $i >file_txt.txt 
fi
done
```

Comment: What's wrong with `cp *.sh sh_files/.; cp *.txt txt_files/.`? Or, if you're just wanting the file names - `ls -1 *.txt > txt_files; ls -1 *.sh > sh_files`...

Answer (score 2):

without writing an additional list_files.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read i
do
    ext="${i/*./}"

    if [ "$ext" = "sh" ]; then
        echo $i >>file_sh.txt
    elif [ "$ext" = "txt" ]; then
        echo $i >>file_txt.txt 
    else 
        echo $i >>file_other.txt 
    fi
done
```

`-maxdepth 1` limits `find` to search only this directory without subdirectories

Comment: Dustin, why you gonna edit the answer that's a trivial copy of mine, dude?

Comment: Sorry - just wanted to show an alternative without writing an separate, intermediate file. And i think, the way with find is better than using ls to restrict the file type.
But i should have written, that is based on your solution.
So - your solution was quite good and i would have used your solution with my optimizations.

Comment: Feel free to add attribution. You can also convert your answer to a community wiki since it's the work of several people.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the extension using rev and cut is probably more complex than it needs to be. Here's a version that calculates the extension by removing everything up to and including the last '.' in the filename. I also used >> instead of > so that the results are appended, rather than overwriting the output file.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -f >list_files.txt

for i in $(cat list_files.txt)
do
    ext="${i/*./}"

    if [ "$ext" = "sh" ]; then
        echo $i >>file_sh.txt
    elif [ "$ext" = "txt" ]; then
        echo $i >>file_txt.txt 
    else 
        echo $i >>file_other.txt 
    fi
done
```